# Arado Websearch - Lookup the URL-Bookmark Database within SQL, any tool available?

Tags: sqlite

installed Arado Websearch ( http://arado.sf.net ) and entered some URLs and my Bookmarks into the Database, which is SQL, is there any tool available to look the Bookmarks up again in the Sql file?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite you, mean. [Download SQLite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/).